# Join using multiple columns

Tags: join, multiple-columns

How do I do the below using JOIN:

```
Select
     id_pk, col1, col2,col
From table1 A
Where NOT EXISTS
  (select 1 from table2 B
    Where A.id_pk = B.id_pk
       and A.col1 = B.col1
       and A.col2 = B.col2
  );
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here, join query cannot be simply used, as we know that both tables share their primary key `id_pk`, we could rather obtain the primary keys of those records which satisfy the conditions `A.id_pk = B.id_pk` (Equi-join), `A.col1 = B.col1` and `A.col2 = B.col2`. And we can use this set of primary keys to obtain those records whose primary keys do not match using `NOT IN` operator. The join query is given as a sub-query, in this case.

Query:

```
SELECT
    id_pk, col1, col2, col
FROM table1 
WHERE id_pk NOT IN (
    SELECT A.id_pk
    FROM table1 A, table2 B
    WHERE A.id_pk = B.id_pk
    AND A.col1 = B.col1
    AND A.col2 = B.col2
);
```